# problema tabla php y html

Tags: php, html, postgresql

hola amigos me encontraba realizando un trabajo y resulta que la tabla me sale con un espacios entre cada dato y se que el problema esta en los <?php o algo por el estilo, llevo horas y no he podido se los agradecería mucho si me ayudan

````
if ($v_tabla=="cliente"){
?>
 <section>
     <h2>CLIENTE</h2>
     <div class="tbl-header">
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>CODIGO CLIENTE</th>
                     <th>NOMBRE CLIENTE</th>
                     <th>TELEFONO CLIENTE</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
         </table>
     </div>
     <?php 
      $sql="select *from $v_tabla ";
      $resultado_set=pg_Exec($conexion, $sql);
             while($row=pg_fetch_array($resultado_set)){
               ?>
     <div class="tbl-content">
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td><?php echo $row["cod_cliente"]?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row["nom_cliente"]?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row["tel_cliente"]?></td>
                 </tr>
                 <?php } ?>
                 <?php } ?>
             </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
 </section>```
````

Comment: Coloca una muestra de cómo están saliendo los datos por favor, pues al momento yo no te capto el problema

Comment: Estás poniendo la etiqueta `table` dentro del `while` en el que se lee cada fila obtenida de la consulta, eso te producirá `N` tablas, donde `N` será el total de filas. Lo lógico sería abrir la etiqueta `table`, así como `tbody` fuera del `while`, luego, dentro del `while` llenas los `tr` y los `td` y fuera del `while` cierras `tbody` y `table`.

Comment: ¿Por qué haces una tabla para encabezados y otra para datos? Es una práctica común cuando quieres mantener los encabezados siempre visibles, pero los datos deberían estar todos en una sola tabla y deberías seguir el consejo de @A.Cedano

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que tu problema es este:

Esta es la estructura de una tabla:

```
   <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

y tú estas poniendo dentro del WHILE()
una tabla entera, por eso te sale con un formato erróneo.

dentro del WHILE deja SOLO los TR por cada registro.